# Get nearest time from array javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, momentjs

I have an object like this

```
var object = {
    "Fajr": "04:29 (WIB)",
    "Sunrise": "05:39 (WIB)",
    "Dhuhr": "11:43 (WIB)",
    "Asr": "14:48 (WIB)",
    "Sunset": "17:48 (WIB)",
    "Maghrib": "17:48 (WIB)",
    "Isha": "18:53 (WIB)",
    "Imsak": "04:19 (WIB)",
    "Midnight": "23:43 (WIB)",
    "Firstthird": "21:45 (WIB)",
    "Lastthird": "01:42 (WIB)"
}
```

and i want to use moment diff https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ . But after searching for couple hours I don't know how to get the nearest time from now.

For example if time now is 11:00 then the time next from the object would be 11:43. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: i want to change it again to object, my bad @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Parse out the times from each entry and sort the results
2. Grab the first one that comes after now
3. If nothing is found, grab the first one from the sorted results as it indicates the next day

```js
var object = {"Fajr":"04:29 (WIB)","Sunrise":"05:39 (WIB)","Dhuhr":"11:43 (WIB)","Asr":"14:48 (WIB)","Sunset":"17:48 (WIB)","Maghrib":"17:48 (WIB)","Isha":"18:53 (WIB)","Imsak":"04:19 (WIB)","Midnight":"23:43 (WIB)","Firstthird":"21:45 (WIB)","Lastthird":"01:42 (WIB)"};

const matcher = /\d+:\d+/;

const parsed = Object.entries(object)
  .map(([key, time]) => {
    const [hour, minute] = time.match(matcher)[0].split(":").map(Number);
    const date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hour, minute, 0, 0);
    return { key, date };
  })
  .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);

const now = new Date();
const {key: next} = parsed.find(({ date }) => now <= date) ?? parsed[0];

console.log("next:", next, object[next]);
```

Comment: Okay this is work, i never thought to use sort like that. Thank u @Phil